# Can you change the unit of prediction in a statistical model?

Tags: time-series

If I do a time series ARIMA model data on monthly data, all future predictions will be at the monthly level.

Is it wrong to take 12 future predictions, add them together, and then say that this will be the cumulative prediction for the next year?

Then, I could do bootstrap method to get confidence interval. Here, I would take a random sample with repeats for whole dataset, fit model, make 12 month prediction, add the 12 month predictions to get cumulative year end prediction .... repeat this process many times ... and then have a bell curve distribution of all cumulative predictions, and take 5 and 95 percentiles of bell curve to get confidences intervals.

The reason I am asking is because I only have 24 months of data. If I want to start with yearly model, it is impossible to fit  time series model on 2 data points. But if I use months, its much easier to fit time series model on 24 points and make 12 month prediction, and then add it at the year end .... indirectly a "hack" for this situation.

Statistically is this ok?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly take 12 months of monthly ARIMA predictions and call the sum a prediction for the entire year.

Your bootstrap idea is a bit questionable. First, bootstrapping will discard any seasonality in your data. Second, you will indeed get something like a confidence interval for your prediction, but are you sure you want that and not a prediction interval? [There is a difference.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info)

> it is impossible to fit time series model on 2 data points

Certainly it is possible. You can take the mean of the two datapoints, or use the most recent one as a naive forecast. You could even fit a trend and extrapolate it out, whether dampened or undampened.

No, none of these will likely be very good forecasts. I personally would put most stock in the average of your two historical annual observations. However, there is not very much you *can* do with just two years of data. Perhaps you can learn something from related time series? Alternatively, take a look at the MAPA algorithm, which would leverage both annual and monthly data.

Comment: I never thought about the interruptions in the bootstrap that will break seasonality ...thx!

Comment: if i add cumulative predictions ... do you know can I get the prediction interval for the added predictions?

Comment: can prediction intervals be added?

Comment: There *is* a notion about bootstrapping in time series... but it is tailored very carefully to preserve seasonalities. And you simply do not have enough data for a lot of very fancy modeling.

Comment: You can always calculate prediction intervals for monthly ARIMA forecasts, then sample or simulate from those, and aggregate simulations. But no matter what you do, the fact remains that you have very little data. I would be *extremely careful* about interpreting *any* kind of prediction interval for annual totals that are based on just two years of history.

Comment: ok so once i fit the model... i can simulate many "hypothetical future paths" that can arise from this model ... and take the prediction interval from here? is my understanding correct?

Comment: Exactly. Simulate 12 monthly futures per your monthly SARIMA model, aggregate the 12 simulations, that is one possible annual total. Do this 1000 times, and take quantiles. (And don't trust the result too much.)

Comment: dont trust results because 12 months is too big in this context?

Comment: No, because you only have two years' historical data. That is very little.